# Change Bitmap Background Color

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-styles

I am Working on Android App which has to change Image Color by Using this library `https://github.com/divyanshub024/ColorSeekBar`, the Issue I am facing is as I Set image background Color, It only changes Borders. I have An `Imageview` that is been Converted from byte array to bitmap and Set into `ImageView`.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_bitmap1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
    />
```

How I am Converting Byte array to Bitmap and Setting into ImageView

```
val byteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("pictures")
    val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
    img_bitmap1.setImageBitmap(bmp)
```

How I am Changing Color

```
 val imageview = requireActivity()!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.img_bitmap1) as ImageView

    color_seek_bar.setOnColorChangeListener(object : ColorSeekBar.OnColorChangeListener {
        override fun onColorChangeListener(color: Int) {
            imageview.setBackgroundColor(color)
        }
    })
```

Comment: May be the image you are decoding has borders only not fill :)

Comment: I have shared my Imageview xml above but I didn't added borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem get Resolved by changing Imageview Color by Getting the Pixel Value, and Only Changing the Pixels that's color is rather than the white..
this Get Achieved by this Method.

```
 var bitmap = (imageviewgradient.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
            var newBitmap = replaceColor(bitmap, color)
```

The Above Code is Converting Image to Bitmap

```
    private fun replaceColor(src: Bitmap?, targetColor: Int): Bitmap? {
    if (src == null) {
        return null
    }
    // Source image size
    val width = src.width
    val height = src.height
    val pixels = IntArray(width * height)
    //get pixels
    src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)
    for (x in pixels.indices) {
        if(pixels[x]!=-1) {
            pixels[x] = targetColor
        }
    }
    // create result bitmap output
    val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.config)
    //set pixels
    result.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)
    return result
}
```

The Main Working is Just Done by a Simple Condition i.e

```
if(pixels[x]!=-1) {
            pixels[x] = targetColor
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

the question is what is showing your `ImageView`, what contains `val bmp` set for it. your seek bar is changing background properly and you see only borders changed, because "center" of image (almost whole) is covered by some `bitmap`

try to NOT load `val bmp` into `ImageView` and check if whole background is changing, not only frame

Comment: Actually I have to load That Into ImageView and after that Change Image Color.

Comment: But I need to Change Image Color

Comment: If I add a View It Changes Its Color Completly But I want is the Content in Imageview color Should Change,

Comment: so you want to colorize image set for `ImageView`, not `ImageView` itself? maybe try to use `imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED);`

Comment: I Got my Problem Resolved By Adding this method and Getting Pixels and If Pixels value is -1, mean White then Only Change the Black Color, I am also adding answer for this

Comment: How would I Only Change Half of ImageView and Other Remains the Black

Comment: in that case you should manipulate `onDraw` method or colorize only half of `Bitmap` - modify your `replaceColor` method

Comment: I have Modified Like but this is Not giving gradient touch it only split Image and give two different Colors
 for (x in pixels.indices) {
            if (x <= 230400) {
                val y = x / 2
                if (pixels[y] != -1) {
                    pixels[y] = targetColor
                }
            }
        }

Comment: this question is about setting background, create new one if you have new problem/case